# How to create instance of service class which has a constructor with a Generic provider(interface) as argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a service class like below

```
public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        private readonly IDbContextProvider<BaseContext> baseContextProvider;

        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public SampleService(IDbContextProvider<BaseContext> baseContextProvider, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.baseContextProvider = baseContextProvider;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
    }

 public interface IDbContextProvider<out T> where T : DbContext
    {

        T Context { get; }
    }
```

I would like to create the instance of `SampleService` class manually. How can i do that ?

Currently I am using simple injector for creating the instances,There is no issues with simple injector instance creation. But for some situation I need to create the instance manually.

I have tried to provide the instance of `BaseContext` while creating the instance of `SampleService` but it doesnt work.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: It's not `BaseContext` that you should provide, but some sort of `BaseContextProvider : IDbContextProvider<BaseContext>` that is not shown in example code.

Comment: can u provide me the syntax ? i got it i have to provide IDbContextProvider<BaseContext>, which is the expected argument , but not sure about the syntax to provide likt that

Comment: `public class SomeSortOfContextProvider : IDbContextProvider<BaseContext> { /* your code goes here */ }`. And then `new SampleService(new SomeSortOfContextProvider(..), new Mapper(..))`.